# Mule HTTPS connector that trusts all certificates

Tags: java, ssl, https, mule

I'm writing integration tests for a Mule ESB application. The Mule application connects to a third-party API via HTTPS. When I try to run my application against the third-party testing API endpoint, everything works fine and I don't have to add any *client* specific SSL configuration to the HTTPS connector. I believe this is due to the fact their server has CA signed certificates, hence they're trusted straight away and e.g. an HTTP connector like this

```
<https:connector
        name="my.https.connector"
        cookieSpec="netscape"
        validateConnections="true"
        sendBufferSize="0"
        receiveBufferSize="0"
        receiveBacklog="0"
        clientSoTimeout="10000"
        serverSoTimeout="10000"
        socketSoLinger="0"
        doc:name="HTTPS">
    <service-overrides sessionHandler="org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler"/>
</https:connector>
```

will work out of the box.

When writing the integration test, I stub (or mock if you prefer) the third-party API. However, in order to make SSL work I have to generate a keystore for the embedded HTTPS server and modify the client HTTPS connector by adding

```
    <https:tls-client path="keystore" storePassword="psw" />
    <https:tls-key-store path="keystore" storePassword="psw" keyPassword="psw" />
```

as mentioned all over the internet.

I could define the testing HTTPS connector in a separated XML file and load it in the `FunctionalTestCase.getConfigResources()` method. However this is not ideal: what I'm really after is a way of making the HTTPS connector (the client) to trust **everything** - but only when running the integration test - i.e. when doing a *Maven* build. This has to happen programmatically in order to leave the Mule application code untouched.

I've tried to add the following code into a `@BeforeClass` annotated method

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-fix-certificate-problem-in-HTTPS.html

but had no luck. I'm still getting the following exception when running the integration tests

```
Exception stack is:
1. unable to find valid certification path to requested target (sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException)
  sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder:196 (null)
2. PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (sun.security.validator.ValidatorException)
  sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator:385 (null)
3. sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException)
  sun.security.ssl.Alerts:192 (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLHandshakeException.html)
```

Anyone with a working solution ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason why you can not just create a test jks file to import into the ESB ecosystem for testing? I'm assuming that the ESB has a test environment from which you run your test cases against.

Comment: Nope sorry, that's not the case. For my integration testing I am running a totally embedded environment, which is brought up/down programmatically during Maven build. This is the whole point of using `Mule Test Compatibility Kit ( TCK )` and that's where the problem with HTTPS comes from.

Comment: So typically in these scenarios where you have an embedded environment where the test framework (in this case Mule) brings up/down a web container, you can ussually include security settings in which the Mule should be able to inject into the container on startup. So the sequence of events should look like follows:

1. Copy jks file into directory
2. Deploy security configuration into web container
3. Deploy application
4. Run test
5. Shutdown

Comment: Ok I think I understand the issue now. You have a Mock Service in which you do not have the proper CA chain so you get a SSL error. The client test is the one experiencing the problem. When you run the client test you want the client to ignore SSL errors only for the duration of the test. In this case I would say that you use the java params for the execution of the test itself:

java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=serverKeys 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=serverTrust 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password SSLApplication

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately that's not a solution that works with `Mule Test Compatibility Kit ( TCK )`. Or at least I wasn't able to make it work.

Comment: No problem, my feeling is that your issue (which is common btw and solved from the client startup params in say jenkins) will not be solved without some file insertion/jvm parameter control from maven. The server in this instance is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Set this in your properties in runtime manager:          com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig.acceptAnyCertificate=true

Configure your pom.xml file as necessary so that it sticks between deploys.